# Fluentd + WebHDFS + kerberos = ошибка "webhdfs check request failed Ticket expired"

Tags: ruby, kerberos

Есть проблема, которую я никак не могу разрешить.
Нужно писать логи в Хадуп. Для этого используем TD-AGENT с плагином WebHDFS.
Вот только он не запускается. Выдает ошибку:

```
    2018-11-28 20:22:19 +0300 [error]: #0 /usr/sbin/td-agent:7:in `<main>'
2018-11-28 20:22:19 +0300 [error]: #0 unexpected error error_class=RuntimeError error="webhdfs is not available now."
  2018-11-28 20:22:19 +0300 [error]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2018-11-28 20:22:19 +0300 [info]: Worker 0 finished unexpectedly with status 1
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-mixin-plaintextformatter' version '0.2.6'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-elasticsearch' version '2.12.1'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-kafka' version '0.6.1'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-mongo' version '0.8.1'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '1.5.6'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-s3' version '0.8.5'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-scribe' version '0.10.14'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td' version '0.10.29'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td-monitoring' version '0.2.3'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-webhdfs' version '1.2.3'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-webhdfs' version '0.7.1'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.3.0'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '0.12.40'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: adding match pattern="hdfs.*.*" type="webhdfs"
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [warn]: #0 'flush_interval' is ignored because default 'flush_mode' is not 'interval': 'lazy'
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: adding source type="http"
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: adding source type="debug_agent"
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [info]: #0 starting fluentd worker pid=5286 ppid=59682 worker=0
2018-11-28 20:22:20 +0300 [warn]: #0 webhdfs check request failed. (namenode: hdp85:50070, error: gss_init_sec_context did not return GSS_S_COMPLETE: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Ticket expired
)
```

Вот такая ошибка, которая непонятно что обозначает.

Есть подозрение, что все дело в авторизации через Цербера.
Но как это решить, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Судя по результатам гугла, всего пару человек сталкивалось с таким.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот не знаю, как у всех, но лично у меня получилось так. Нужно:

1. войти под юзером td-agent. Причем это неполноценный юзер, и шела у него нет.
2. прописать переменную окружения KRB5_CONFIG.
3. закинитить его

   - sudo -u td-agent bash
   - export KRB5_CONFIG=/etc/krb5.conf
   - kinit -kt /var/lib/td-agent/td-agent.keytab td-agent

Только после этого у меня Флюнт начал писать в ХДФС.